# MongoDB windows server Error : Too many open files

Tags: windows, mongodb, text, indexing, server

We use Windows Server 2012 on our machine.
When I try to create a text index an error occur after %50.

MongoDB v3.0.4 
290GB database size 30m row at collection

How can i solve this problem?

```
> db.myCollection.ensureIndex({myField:1}, {name: "myIndex"})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "error opening file \"E:\\MongoDB\\base1\\_tmp\extsort.509\":errno:24 Too many open files",
    "code" : 16818
}
```

Comment: Switch to Orthodox Linux?.... :)

Comment: The correct way to create a text index in MongoDB v3.0.4 is `db.myCollection.createIndex(
                           { "myField": "text" },
                           { name: "TextIndex" }
                         )`

Comment: See here: http://serverfault.com/questions/249477/windows-server-2008-r2-max-open-files-limit Inspect your open files with net config server.